# Error while using DateLocator and DateFormatter with Matplotlib and Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is the code that is working:

```
df = pd.read_csv("aSeries.csv", parse_dates=['Date'])
print(df.info())
ax = sns.barplot(x="Date" , y="y", data=df, color= "darkgray")
```

the info() display the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 122 entries, 0 to 121
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Date    122 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   y       118 non-null    float64
```

This works only ok: there are too many dates so we can't see them properly. So I tried the following:

```
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=2)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

And here I get the following error:

> ValueError: view limit minimum -0.5 is less than 1 and is an invalid
>   Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime
>   value to an axis that has datetime units

I used the following libraries version:

- Seaborn version  0.10.0
- Pandas version  1.0.1
- matplotlib version 3.1.3

Comment: `barplot` plots the data against `range()` and put the date as ticks. So your plot does not have a date axis.

Comment: Thank you! This answer the question.